# schedule job at a particular time using agenda node js

Tags: node.js, agenda

I want to schedule job at a particular time using agenda node js

```
var agenda = new Agenda();
agenda.define('initA', function(job) {
  console.log("INITA AGENDA");

  job.repeatAt('at 13:25');
  job.save();
});

agenda.on('ready', function() {
  console.log("Agenda ready to start");
  agenda.start();
});
```

Comment: what happened when you tried this ?

Comment: not scheduling a job at a given time @Sikorski

Comment: repeatAt just takes time, if you omit "at" and just provide the time it should work

Comment: the thing is a time will be given to me like 15:00 and i have to execute a job 2 hrs before the given time means at 13:00 Hrs using agenda

Comment: can u provide me the sample code for the same @Sikorski

Comment: it is printing INIT AGENDA automatically after every 30 seconds.

Comment: just remove "at" from the string that you are passing to repeatAt. Look at the docs pls

Comment: i did @Sikorski but then it is sending me the message after every 30seconds rather than executing a job only once and a particular given time

Answer (score 0):

### To schedule job at a particular time using agenda

first you must Create a job Processor - which define its processing behavior.

```
agenda.define('initA', function(job) {

  console.log("INITA AGENDA");

  job.repeatAt('at 13:25');

  job.save();

});
```

Then use either 1. or 2.

1. agenda.Create(jobName, data)

```
const job = agenda.create('initA', { id: 1 });
            job.schedule('tomorrow at 6pm');
            await job.save();
```

2. agenda.schedule(when, name, [data])

as shown below

```
agenda.schedule('tomorrow at noon', 'initA', { id: 1 });
```